# How do i output the probability of a single prediction being correct?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using random forest classifier on titanic dataset. Instead of outputting whether a passenger survives or not, I would instead like to output the probability of a passenger surviving. Is that possible using Random forest?

The current output is either 0 or 1. I'd like the response to be for example: 87% chance of surviving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the `.predict()` method? Instead you can use the `.predict_proba()`

> Predict class probabilities for X.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba